# div collapses when slideshow is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have this code which almost works the way I want. It's a portfolio site, where upon clicking every `.Title-line` the div toggles and displays a slideshow where the visitor of the page is able to go trough the project.

My problem now is that when a project toggles and I click the arrows in the slideshow, the entire div closes immediately.

Is it possible to modify the javascript in such a way that each `.Title-line` is assigned a div, and it's only when someone clicks outside of both of them that the div collapses again?

```js
var iShown = 0;

function Show_Content(iContent) {
  if (iShown > 0) {
    document.getElementById("content" + iShown).style.display = "none";
  }

  if (iContent !== iShown) {
    document.getElementById("content" + iContent).style.display = "block";
    iShown = iContent;
  } else {
    iShown = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.mySlides1,
.mySlides2,
.mySlides3,
.mySlides4,
.mySlides5,
.mySlides6,
.mySlides7,
.mySlides8,
.mySlides9,
.mySlides10,
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  src: url('lirma-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('lirma-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}


/* Information line in the top */

.Headline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
}

.Headline_1 {
  flex: 1;
  Align: center;
}

.Headline_2 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_3 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_4 {
  flex: 1;
  position: center;
  text-align: right;
}


/* Project and year */

.Title-line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}

.Title-line-01 {
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  font-size: 25px;
}

.Title-line-02 {
  flex: 1;
}

.Title-line-03 {
  flex: 1;
}

.Title-line-04 {
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/* Specific projectnames */

.ProjectName-01 {
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  font-size: 25px;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
}


/* Specific contents */

.content-01 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
}

.Flexbox_1 {
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Flexbox_2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.Flexbox_3 {
  flex: 1;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a grey background color */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Headline">
  <div class="Headline_1">Carina Thornval</div>
  <div class="Headline_2">mail@cthornval.com</div>
  <div class="Headline_3">+4571580488</div>
  <div class="Headline_4">Curriculum vitae available upon request</div>
</div>
<div onclick="Show_Content(1)" class="Project">
  <div class="Title-line">
    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Region H</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2021</p>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="content1" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>
      <p>
        School Project <br> Strategic design proposal
        <br> <br> The Health and innovation unit of the Capital Region of
        <br> <br>

        <br> <br>

        <a href="link"> Click here
                          </a>

      </p>
    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>
      <div class="slideshow-container">


        <div class="mySlides1">
          <img src="Images/01_REG H/Instagram - landscape copy.mov" type="video/mp4" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div onclick="Show_Content(2)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>CIFF</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2020</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content2" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>
      <p>
        School Project
        <br> Strategic design
        <br> <br> We were presented with the challenge of rethinking CIFF´s business model as the organisation was facing mounting challenges, as they were prohibited from throwing their annual fashion fair at Bella Center, because of the outbreak of
        the coronavirus. Therefor we proposed a new format for their trade fair: A digital platform, where brands and buyers can engage online through payingf a monthly subscription. Moreover brands are invited to rent a physical "stage”/pavillion from
        where they can livestream content, through for example throwing events or having a showroom. The content produced will then reciprocally be distributed on the online platform. The stage is a modular and mobile architectural entity, which can be
        placed all over the country and where the interior can be adapted to suit the needs of the brand renting the stage.
        <br> <br> This project was a collaboration with Fie Eleonora Mortensen, Gustavo Garcia og Laura Winter-Poulsen.
        <br> <br>

        <a href="">
                      Images and video
                    </a>
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">



        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_01 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_02 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_03 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_04 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_05 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_06 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_07 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_07 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(3)" class="Project">


  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Sofia Bordoni</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2020</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content3" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Webpage design and development
      </p>
      <br>
      <br>

      <a href="">
                  click here
                </a>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="Images/03_Sofia Bordoni/SofiaBord.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(4)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Lirma Type</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2020</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content4" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Typedesign
      </p>

      <br>
      <br>
      <a href="">
                      Click here
                    </a>


    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides4">
          <img src="Images/04_Lirma/type_new copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 3)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 3)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(5)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Wer Baut Der Stadt</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2018</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content5" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Identity and Font developed for the lecture series on architecture conducted by No Image in Berlin.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides5">
          <img src="Images/05_WER BAUT 2018/Wer_baut copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides5">
          <img src="Images/05_WER BAUT 2018/Poster_Wer_baut.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 4)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 4)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div onclick="Show_Content(6)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>CAFX</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2018</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content6" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>
      <p>
        Identity Design for Copenhagen Architecture Festival
        <br> 2018
      </p>


    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>
      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_red_poster.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_green_poster.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_blue_poster.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/IMG_0546 (1)_Cafx_7-kopi.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/IMG_0546 (1)_Cafx_8-kopi.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 5)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 5)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div onclick="Show_Content(7)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Contagious Tales</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content7" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Graduation project, editorial design.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides7">
          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_01 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides7">
          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_02 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides7">
          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 6)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 6)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(8)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>FOAM X HYDRA</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content8" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Design of exhibition cahier in connection to the exhibition FOAM X HYDRA
        <p>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_01.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_02.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_3.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_04.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_05.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 7)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 7)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(9)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Money Publication</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content9" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Publication design with text by Christopher Deutschmann and Paul Larfague
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_6 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_1 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_4 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_5 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 8)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 8)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div onclick="Show_Content(10)" class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>What is the newsarticle?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content10" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>
      <p>
        Publication design with text by Christopher Deutschmann and Paul Larfague
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides10">
          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/Newsletter_1 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides10">
          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/newsletter_2 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides10">
          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/newsletter_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 9)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 9)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to close a project without opening another one, you just have to move the onclick one div down the code:

```
<div onclick="Show_Content(1)" class="Project">
    <div class="Title-line">
```

Should become:

```
<div class="Project">
    <div onclick="Show_Content(1)" class="Title-line">
```

Now here's that piece of javascript, fixed in order to close a project only when you open a different one:

```
var iShown = 0;

function Show_Content(iContent) {
    if (iShown == 0) {
        document.getElementById("content" + iContent).style.display = "block";
    } else if (iContent !== iShown) {
        document.getElementById("content" + iShown).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("content" + iContent).style.display = "block";
    }
    iShown = iContent;
}
```

If you only change the javascript, a project will never close once opened.

If you change the javascript and the placement of the onclick event (you gotta move the onclick event from the outter div, class "Project", to the inner one, class "Title-line"), then you can close a project by clicking on it again, or by opening a different one.

Comment: Sorry, for late reply. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: You're welcome :-)

Comment: But you forgot to accept the anwer... :-)

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can use DOM traversal to find the `.content` within the clicked `.project`. From there you can add a class to it to display it, while removing that same class from all other `.content` elements. Try this:

```js
let $content = $('.content');

let $projects = $('.Project').on('click', e => {
  let $target = $(e.currentTarget).find('.content').addClass('active');
  $content.not($target).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.mySlides1,
.mySlides2,
.mySlides3,
.mySlides4,
.mySlides5,
.mySlides6,
.mySlides7,
.mySlides8,
.mySlides9,
.mySlides10,
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  src: url('lirma-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('lirma-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}


/* Information line in the top */

.Headline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
}

.Headline_1 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_2 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_3 {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Headline_4 {
  flex: 1;
  position: center;
  text-align: right;
}


/* Project and year */

.Project.active {
  display: block;
}
.Title-line {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row
}

.Title-line-01 {
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  font-size: 25px;
}

.Title-line-02 {
  flex: 1;
}

.Title-line-03 {
  flex: 1;
}

.Title-line-04 {
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 25px;
}


/* Specific projectnames */

.ProjectName-01 {
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'lirmaregular';
  font-size: 25px;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
}
.content.active {
  display: block;
}


/* Specific contents */

.content-01 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: wrap;
}

.Flexbox_1 {
  flex: 1;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
  font-size: 20px;
}

.Flexbox_2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.Flexbox_3 {
  flex: 1;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a grey background color */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Headline">
  <div class="Headline_1">Carina Thornval</div>
  <div class="Headline_2">mail@cthornval.com</div>
  <div class="Headline_3">+4571580488</div>
  <div class="Headline_4">Curriculum vitae available upon request</div>
</div>
<div class="Project">
  <div class="Title-line">
    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Region H</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Title-line-02"></div>
    <div class="Title-line-03"></div>
    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2021</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content1" class="content">
    <div class=Flexbox_1>
      <p>
        School Project <br> Strategic design proposal<br> <br> The Health and innovation unit of the Capital Region of<br><br><br> <br>
        <a href="link"> Click here</a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>
      <div class="slideshow-container">
        <div class="mySlides1">
          <img src="Images/01_REG H/Instagram - landscape copy.mov" type="video/mp4" style="width:100%">
        </div>
        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 0)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 0)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="Project">
  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>CIFF</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2020</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content2" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>
      <p>
        School Project
        <br> Strategic design
        <br> <br> We were presented with the challenge of rethinking CIFF´s business model as the organisation was facing mounting challenges, as they were prohibited from throwing their annual fashion fair at Bella Center, because of the outbreak of
        the coronavirus. Therefor we proposed a new format for their trade fair: A digital platform, where brands and buyers can engage online through payingf a monthly subscription. Moreover brands are invited to rent a physical "stage”/pavillion from
        where they can livestream content, through for example throwing events or having a showroom. The content produced will then reciprocally be distributed on the online platform. The stage is a modular and mobile architectural entity, which can be
        placed all over the country and where the interior can be adapted to suit the needs of the brand renting the stage.
        <br> <br> This project was a collaboration with Fie Eleonora Mortensen, Gustavo Garcia og Laura Winter-Poulsen.
        <br> <br>

        <a href="">
                      Images and video
                    </a>
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">



        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_01 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_02 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_03 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_04 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_05 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_06 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_07 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides2">
          <img src="Images/02_CIFF/PSD_Archiitecture_07 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="Project">


  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Sofia Bordoni</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2020</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content3" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Webpage design and development
      </p>
      <br>
      <br>

      <a href="">
                  click here
                </a>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides3">
          <img src="Images/03_Sofia Bordoni/SofiaBord.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 2)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 2)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Lirma Type</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2020</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content4" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Typedesign
      </p>

      <br>
      <br>
      <a href="">
                      Click here
                    </a>


    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides4">
          <img src="Images/04_Lirma/type_new copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 3)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 3)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Wer Baut Der Stadt</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2018</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content5" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Identity and Font developed for the lecture series on architecture conducted by No Image in Berlin.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides5">
          <img src="Images/05_WER BAUT 2018/Wer_baut copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides5">
          <img src="Images/05_WER BAUT 2018/Poster_Wer_baut.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 4)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 4)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>CAFX</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2018</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content6" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>
      <p>
        Identity Design for Copenhagen Architecture Festival
        <br> 2018
      </p>


    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>
      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_red_poster.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_green_poster.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/Wer_baut_blue_poster.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/IMG_0546 (1)_Cafx_7-kopi.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides6">
          <img src="Images/06_CAFX/IMG_0546 (1)_Cafx_8-kopi.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 5)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 5)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Contagious Tales</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content7" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Graduation project, editorial design.
      </p>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides7">
          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_01 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides7">
          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_02 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides7">
          <img src="Images/07_Contagious Tales/Contagious_tales_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 6)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 6)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>FOAM X HYDRA</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content8" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Design of exhibition cahier in connection to the exhibition FOAM X HYDRA
        <p>

    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_01.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_02.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_3.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_04.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides8">
          <img src="Images/08_FOAM/FoamXHydra_05.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 7)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 7)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>Money Publication</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content9" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>

      <p>
        Publication design with text by Christopher Deutschmann and Paul Larfague
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_6 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_1 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_4 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides9">
          <img src="Images/09_Money Publication/_97A0746-kopi 2_5 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 8)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 8)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="Project">

  <div class="Title-line">

    <div class="Title-line-01">
      <p>What is the newsarticle?</p>
    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-02">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-03">

    </div>

    <div class="Title-line-04">
      <p>2017</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="content10" class="content">

    <div class=Flexbox_1>
      <p>
        Publication design with text by Christopher Deutschmann and Paul Larfague
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class=Flexbox_2></div>
    <div class=Flexbox_3>

      <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides10">
          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/Newsletter_1 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides10">
          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/newsletter_2 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>

        <div class="mySlides10">
          <img src="Images/10_Newsarticle/newsletter_3 copy.png" style="width:100%">
        </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1, 9)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1, 9)">&#10095;</a>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```